# get the id of the table row onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Requirement is to get the value of the id on click on any of the table row data.

Please find the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/T887t/55/

Below is the javascript i tried:

```
<script>
    function test(){
      alert("test called");
      var serviceID = $(this).attr('id');
      alert("serviceID :: " + serviceID);
    }
</script>
```

html code:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th><b> Column1 </b> </th>
    <th><b> Column2 </b> </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="navigateTest" id="88" onclick="test()"> Row1 - Data1 </td> 
    <td class="navigateTest" id="98" onclick="test()"> Row1 - Data2  </td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="navigateTest" id="33" onclick="test()"> Row2 -  Data1  </td> 
    <td class="navigateTest" id="55" onclick="test()"> Row2 - Data2  </td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

Could not able to get the value of the id in javascript function. The value of the id is dynamic on my application. Please suggest.

Comment: Have a look at this: [HTML5 Data Attributes](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/).
They are very easy to access from jQuery.

Comment: This is not keyboard accessible. Put `<button>`s in the `<td>`s and attach the click handler to the buttons instead.

Comment: your `onclick` function doesn't provide you with access to `this`without passing arguments in

Comment: Can we achieve this using plain javascript as jquery is not supported in my application. Thanks.

Comment: `var serviceID = $(this).attr('id');` is jQuery... How is this not supported in your app if you are using it?  In plain JS that would be `var serviceID = this.id;`

Answer (score 8):

If you are going to use jQuery, then use its event binding as well

```
$('.navigateTest').click(function(){
 alert("test called");
 var serviceID = this.id;
 alert("serviceID :: " + serviceID);
});
```

You will no longer need to inline `onclick=test()` with this snippet.

This will query for all of the elements with class=nagivateTest and assign a click handler to them. Once clicked, `this` will refer to the element clicked inside of the callback.

The reason your original code does not work is because `this` in the global callback is `window` and will not relate to the current element clicked.

If you are going to include this code in the head or in a linked file, make sure to wrap the code in the ready callback so that the DOM has been parsed and the `.navigateTest` elements are available. That would look like this:

```
$(function(){ //jQuery shortcut for .ready (ensures DOM ready)
 $('.navigateTest').click(function(){
  alert("test called");
  var serviceID = this.id;
  alert("serviceID :: " + serviceID);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T887t/58/).

Using plain javascript you can use event listeners to run only when the table is clicked. Using event listeners avoids the need to inline javascript Which is considered bad practice (when it can be avoided) and results in cleaner and easier to maintain / read code. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) for more information on event listener.

```
<script>
    // get a reference to the table
    var table = document.querySelector('table');

    // listen for a click
    table.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
        // get the event targets ID
        var serviceID = ev.target.id;
        alert(serviceID);
    })
</script>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
         <th><b> Column1 </b> </th>
         <th><b> Column2 </b> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td class="navigateTest" id="88"> Row1 - Data1 </td> 
        <td class="navigateTest" id="98"> Row1 - Data2  </td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="navigateTest" id="33"> Row2 -  Data1  </td> 
        <td class="navigateTest" id="55"> Row2 - Data2  </td>    
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the inline event handlers and use:

```js
$('.navigateTest').click(function () {
    alert("test called");
    var serviceID = $(this).attr('id');
    alert("serviceID :: " + serviceID);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th><b> Column1 </b> 
        </th>
        <th><b> Column2 </b> 
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="navigateTest" id="88">Row1 - Data1</td>
        <td class="navigateTest" id="98">Row1 - Data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="navigateTest" id="33">Row2 - Data1</td>
        <td class="navigateTest" id="55">Row2 - Data2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In my application, it's not working. I think jquery is not supporting in my application. Can we achieve this using plain javascript. Please suggest.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th><b> Column1 </b> </th>
    <th><b> Column2 </b> </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="navigateTest" id="88" onclick="test(88)"> Row1 - Data1 </td> 
    <td class="navigateTest" id="98" onclick="test(98)"> Row1 - Data2  </td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="navigateTest" id="33" onclick="test(33)"> Row2 -  Data1  </td> 
    <td class="navigateTest" id="55" onclick="test(55)"> Row2 - Data2  </td>    
  </tr>
</table>

function test(id)
{
var id = id;
}
```